# Change camera settings in OpenCV

Tags: c++, function, opencv, camera, settings

How can I change the two sides of camera capturing?

I am making a desktop application that can capture a video using a camera. But my camera captures left side as right side and right side as left side. I need to record the opposite: right side as right side and left side as left side. I use the video capture function in C++.

Comment: If you would add some code detailing what you are doing to come up with your result in question, that would help getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's only flipped when you preview on screen. So to fix that you can do

```
Mat frame, flippedFrame;
VideoCapture capture(0);

while (1){
       cap>> frame;
       flip(frame, flippedFrame,0);

       imshow("flipped", flippedFrame);
       // rest of code here
}
```